# What is the cost of initializing a for loop counter? Why use int rather than byte?

Tags: for-loop, iterator, integer, byte, counter

What is the speed cost of creating, iterating, and disposing a for loop counter?

From what I've read it sounds like, for most CPUs and in most scenarios, working with bytes isn't any faster than working with int, or if it is the difference is very small.

I'm curious about for loops though, since there's no type conversion or chance of overflow or any other reason to prefer an int - but in every example I've ever seen, the counter was an int. Is there a reason for that?

I ask because my project has a lot of nested for loops iterating over small multidimensional arrays. Would it improve performance to use a byte, or some other type smaller than an int?

Comment: i could be wrong but, i am not sure, this is something to discuss in this community. you are looking for opinions and ideas but we are more about specific questions and solutions to those specific problems. it would better if you already did some steps on your own, had some data indicating costs related to loop counter, and you want advise on the code you used to obtain this data. right now, this is just opinion seeking.

Comment: Thanks. Can you think of another stack exchange that would be better for this?

I don't agree it's **opinion** seeking per se, I want to understand for loop counters better on a basic technical level, the rest of the stuff is context. But even so I agree this might not be the best fit for stackoverflow

Comment: i agree with you as well, that you are seeking more than just opinions. but you got what i was talking about, so we are good :). on the community, people mention super user site a lot. try  your luck there.

Comment: https://superuser.com/